# Create a lambda expression to query data

Tags: c#, json, lambda

I created some classes based on the json data in order to deserialize the json data.
I would like to access the sku and the skuName using a lambda expression but i am unable to do so.

So managed to get the skuName, but how do i get sku property? i want to get the skuName property and the associated sku property as well. skuName and sku belong to the same class- SKU class. Thanks for your time

```
    var productSku = skuIdName.BodyText.products.vendors
         .SelectMany(x => x.listings
        .SelectMany(l => l.skus
        .SelectMany(f => f.skuName

         ))).ToArray();
```

I am unable to obtain ALL the skus and sdkuName (using lambda) and put it in a list or a dictionary using the sku value as Key and the skuName as the value, as i would later like to store these values in a database.
e.g.
"sku": "SK8772",
"skuName": "Domestic and International Calling Plan",
"sku": "SK8265",
"skuName": "Audio Conferencing",

```
     JSON DATA:

 {
   "Result": "Success",
   "BodyText": 
  {
  "products": 
{
  "totalProducts": 510,
  "recordsPerPage": 10,
  "page": 1,
  "totalPages": 51,
  "vendors": [
    {
      "vendorId": "397",
      "vendorName": "Microsoft",
      "listings": [
        {
          "listingName": "Office 365 Enterprise",
          "skus": [
            {
              "sku": "SK10228",
              "skuName": "Microsoft 365 E5 without Audio Conferencing",
              "description": "Pending",
              "zeroValueSku": "t",
              "manufacturerPartNumber": "db5e0b1c9cc3459c9d08c61993959fd3",
              "article": "4090153",
              "vendorMapId": "db5e0b1c-9cc3-459c-9d08-c61993959fd3",
              "billingType": "Monthly",
              "productType": "SaaS",
              "qtyMin": "1",
              "qtyMax": "",
              "addOns": [
                {
                  "sku": "SK8265",
                  "skuName": "Audio Conferencing",
                  "description": "For businesses that need to enable users to dial-in a number to join Skype meetings, or dial-out to bring participants into the meeting. There are base pre-requisites required to purchase this offering.",
                  "zeroValueSku": "t",
                  "qtyMin": "1",
                  "qtyMax": "",
                  "vendorMapId": "c94271d8-b431-4a25-a3c5-a57737a1c909",
                  "manufacturerPartNumber": "c94271d8b4314a25a3c5a57737a1c909",
                  "article": "3873033"
                },
                {
                  "sku": "SK8772",
                  "skuName": "Domestic and International Calling Plan",
                  "description": "For Businesses that need to enable online users to place or receive Domestic and International calls through the Public Switched Telephone Network (PSTN). There are base pre-requisites required to purchase this offering.",
                  "zeroValueSku": "t",
                  "qtyMin": "1",
                  "qtyMax": "",
                  "vendorMapId": "ded34535-507f-4246-8370-f9180318c537",
                  "manufacturerPartNumber": "ded34535507f42468370f9180318c537",
                  "article": "3968760"
                },
              }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
},
  "Key": 3298012
}


    public class AddOn
     {
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string skuName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string zeroValueSku { get; set; }
    public string qtyMin { get; set; }
    public string qtyMax { get; set; }
    public string vendorMapId { get; set; }
    public string manufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string article { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}

public class Sku
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string skuName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string zeroValueSku { get; set; }
    public string manufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string article { get; set; }
    public string vendorMapId { get; set; }
    public string billingType { get; set; }
    public string productType { get; set; }
    public string qtyMin { get; set; }
    public string qtyMax { get; set; }
    public List<AddOn> addOns { get; set; }
    public List<string> datacenterLocations { get; set; }
    public List<AddOn2> add { get; set; }
}

public class AddOn2
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string skuName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string zeroValueSku { get; set; }
    public string qtyMin { get; set; }
    public string qtyMax { get; set; }
    public string manufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string article { get; set; }

    public List<Sku> sk { get; set; }
}

public class Listing
{
    public string listingName { get; set; }
    public List<Sku> skus { get; set; }
    public List<AddOn2> addOns { get; set; }

    //new
    //public List<AddOn2> addon2s { get; set; }
}

public class Vendor
{
    public string vendorId { get; set; }
    public string vendorName { get; set; }//microsoft
    public List<Listing> listings { get; set; }

   // public List<Sku> skus { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public int totalProducts { get; set; }
    public int recordsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int totalPages { get; set; }
    public List<Vendor> vendors { get; set; }
}

public class BodyText
{
    public Products products { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public BodyText BodyText { get; set; }
    public int Key { get; set; }
}
  }



   RootObject skuIdName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonStorageProducts);
```

Comment: you are not able to figure out how to write the expression? Or you wrote it and cant get the values correctly?

Comment: Your Json is invalid. Correcting it, you get the value "Microsoft" that your Linq should return. What is your problem really?

Comment: I am unable to figure out the expression to get all the sku and skuName

Comment: Just added a answer.... I didnt write in VS so might be slightly off... should give you an idea on how to get to it using lambda.

Comment: Remove the FirstOrDefault(). You are explicitly asking it to return only first one if exists. In your JSON there is only one at the moment.

Comment: i removed the FirstOrDefault() but unable to retrieve the sku and skuName

Comment: Check my answer. should help you to understand what you need to do

Comment: @NarendranPandian, your answer don't answer the question, does it? He doesn't want that sku but the one in addons array. Also, should be a typo but you have an invalid root there.

Comment: You can simply use SelectMany as I showed.

Comment: @CetinBasoz My understanding is that the OP's is unable to use lambda expression to query data out of his JSON. I was trying to help the OP understand how you can query stuff to reach yours or other answer posted here.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you meant this:

```
void Main()
{
    string jsonStorageProducts = @"
{
   ""Result"": ""Success"",
   ""BodyText"": 
  {
  ""products"": 
{
  ""totalProducts"": 510,
  ""recordsPerPage"": 10,
  ""page"": 1,
  ""totalPages"": 51,
  ""vendors"": [
    {
      ""vendorId"": ""397"",
      ""vendorName"": ""Microsoft"",
      ""listings"": [
        {
          ""listingName"": ""Office 365 Enterprise"",
          ""skus"": [
            {
              ""sku"": ""SK10228"",
              ""skuName"": ""Microsoft 365 E5 without Audio Conferencing"",
              ""description"": ""Pending"",
              ""zeroValueSku"": ""t"",
              ""manufacturerPartNumber"": ""db5e0b1c9cc3459c9d08c61993959fd3"",
              ""article"": ""4090153"",
              ""vendorMapId"": ""db5e0b1c-9cc3-459c-9d08-c61993959fd3"",
              ""billingType"": ""Monthly"",
              ""productType"": ""SaaS"",
              ""qtyMin"": ""1"",
              ""qtyMax"": """",
              ""addOns"": [
                {
                  ""sku"": ""SK8265"",
                  ""skuName"": ""Audio Conferencing"",
                  ""description"": ""For businesses that need to enable users to dial-in a number to join Skype meetings, or dial-out to bring participants into the meeting. There are base pre-requisites required to purchase this offering."",
                  ""zeroValueSku"": ""t"",
                  ""qtyMin"": ""1"",
                  ""qtyMax"": """",
                  ""vendorMapId"": ""c94271d8-b431-4a25-a3c5-a57737a1c909"",
                  ""manufacturerPartNumber"": ""c94271d8b4314a25a3c5a57737a1c909"",
                  ""article"": ""3873033""
                },
                {
                  ""sku"": ""SK8772"",
                  ""skuName"": ""Domestic and International Calling Plan"",
                  ""description"": ""For Businesses that need to enable online users to place or receive Domestic and International calls through the Public Switched Telephone Network (PSTN). There are base pre-requisites required to purchase this offering."",
                  ""zeroValueSku"": ""t"",
                  ""qtyMin"": ""1"",
                  ""qtyMax"": """",
                  ""vendorMapId"": ""ded34535-507f-4246-8370-f9180318c537"",
                  ""manufacturerPartNumber"": ""ded34535507f42468370f9180318c537"",
                  ""article"": ""3968760""
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
},
  ""Key"": 3298012
}
";
    RootObject skuIdName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonStorageProducts);
    var productSku = skuIdName.BodyText.products.vendors
     .SelectMany(x =>x.listings
     .SelectMany(l => l.skus
     .SelectMany(s => s.addOns
     .Select(o => new { 
        SKU = o.sku, 
        Name = o.skuName }))));

    foreach (var sku in productSku)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"SKU: {sku.SKU}, Name: {sku.Name}");
    }
}


public class AddOn
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string skuName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string zeroValueSku { get; set; }
    public string qtyMin { get; set; }
    public string qtyMax { get; set; }
    public string vendorMapId { get; set; }
    public string manufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string article { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}

public class Sku
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string skuName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string zeroValueSku { get; set; }
    public string manufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string article { get; set; }
    public string vendorMapId { get; set; }
    public string billingType { get; set; }
    public string productType { get; set; }
    public string qtyMin { get; set; }
    public string qtyMax { get; set; }
    public List<AddOn> addOns { get; set; }
    public List<string> datacenterLocations { get; set; }
    public List<AddOn2> add { get; set; }
}

public class AddOn2
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string skuName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string zeroValueSku { get; set; }
    public string qtyMin { get; set; }
    public string qtyMax { get; set; }
    public string manufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string article { get; set; }

    public List<Sku> sk { get; set; }
}

public class Listing
{
    public string listingName { get; set; }
    public List<Sku> skus { get; set; }
    public List<AddOn2> addOns { get; set; }

    //new
    //public List<AddOn2> addon2s { get; set; }
}

public class Vendor
{
    public string vendorId { get; set; }
    public string vendorName { get; set; }//microsoft
    public List<Listing> listings { get; set; }

    // public List<Sku> skus { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public int totalProducts { get; set; }
    public int recordsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int totalPages { get; set; }
    public List<Vendor> vendors { get; set; }
}

public class BodyText
{
    public Products products { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public BodyText BodyText { get; set; }
    public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
SKU: SK8265, Name: Audio Conferencing
SKU: SK8772, Name: Domestic and International Calling Plan
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lambda expression that might help you to take the values you require. Below is an example to get list of SKUs.

```
var root = new RootObject();
var skus = new List<Sku>();
root.BodyText.products.vendors.ForEach(vendor =>
        vendor.listings.ForEach(listing => listing.skus.ForEach(sku => skus.Add(sku))));
```

The above code will get you the SKUs of all the vendors of all listings and so on. Now using this as an example you should be able to proceed. If you need further help do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ForEach` of `LINQ` to iterate over the model and populate a dictionary as follows:

```
var nameIdDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

skuIdName.BodyText.products.vendors.ForEach(v => 
{
    v.Listings.ForEach(listing => 
    {
        listing.skus.ForEach(s => 
        {
            nameIdDict.Add(s.sku, s.skuName);
            s.addOns.ForEach(a => 
            {
                nameIdDict.Add(a.sku, a.skuName);
            });
            s.add.ForEach(a => 
            {
                nameIdDict.Add(a.sku, a.skuName);
            });
        });
        listing.addOns.ForEach(a => 
        {
            nameIdDict.Add(a.sku, a.skuName);
        });
    });
});
```

Ultimately you should get the `sku` and respective `skuNames` in the dictionary. Though you won't be knowing at which level in the json it existed.

Comment: You were close but not quite. Maybe you want to edit your answer to return what he wants:  skuIdName.BodyText.products.vendors.ForEach(v =>
 {
  v.listings.ForEach(listing =>
  {
   listing.skus.ForEach(s =>
   {
    s.addOns.ForEach(a =>
    {
     nameIdDict.Add(a.sku, a.skuName);
    });
   });
  });
 });

Comment: @CetinBasoz close but not quite...why? is it becoz I have added sku and skuNames from other places also?

Comment: Nope, just corrected your typos and removed one extra level you added. You can quickly test your code and the corrected one, I already provided the code in my answer. You can copy paste there and test what you get. Your code wouldn't run as is.

Comment: @CetinBasoz in your code, you are fetching the 'addOns` within the 'skus' within the 'listings' collection...right? But what about the 'addOns' within 'listings' object and the 'add' within the 'sku' object? these would also have sku and skuName information

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but anyway read what he wants.

Comment: @CetinBasoz As per your solution...we are going to get the sku and skuName properties from the 'addOns' that are present within 'skus' which  are present within 'listings'...however, there is a property called 'add' within 'sku' model which also has 'sku' and 'skuName' properties. Your solution is not giving out those.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Where did u read that it is to be excluded. I could advise you the same thing about reading the question

Comment: It is up there :) e.g. "sku": "SK8772", "skuName": "Domestic and International Calling Plan", "sku": "SK8265", "skuName": "Audio Conferencing",

Comment: @CetinBasoz I consider that as an example and not as a condition :)